# SSRS subreport header fixed

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I'm having a real hard time figuring if this is possible in SSRS.  I have a report with three levels(summary, parent and child).  The parent is set as a subreport of the summary and child a subreport of parent.  Each level has field headers, I can get the summary headers to stay fixed(like excel freeze panes), but can't figure out any way to make the header of the parent or child sub report stay fixed so they don't scroll off the top of the page.

Is this doable?

Comment: Are they really subreports? Maybe you mean subgroups?

Comment: No, I've set them up as sub reports.  When I run them as sub groups I get an only outermost level of tablix can have fixed data property set.    Really trying to get this to behave like Excel where the freeze pane can be moved depending on which level of the report you are looking at.